# Xcode Build Succeed But Code Is Not Running

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I have some problems and I need help. When I open a new project in c++ and compile that project, code is running. But few times later I can not run the code. xcode says "Build succeed" but I can't see anything on xcode's terminal. And when I was creating a new project, I see "Git Repository Creation Failed" writing on screen. Please help me

I tried everything but I couldn't fix the problem.Here is the screenshot.Please help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y29ot.png)

Comment: It happens sometimes in some XCode versions. Probably an elusive bug. 

Try stopping the running application and run it again. Usually it helps.

As of Git error -- well, have you initialized git on your machine? XCode won't do it, you have to do it yourself before XCode would be able to use git.